# Folium returns the errors validate_locations and <listcomp>

Tags: python, elasticsearch, folium

In this code, I have stored zipcodes in 'zipcodes'. With the function find_location I find the latitude and longitude of this zipcode in ElasticSearch. Then, this lat and lon are added to a new array (points).
After that, all of the points are added in one go to the array and eventually the map is created using the Polyline function.

```py
# create for each address of the chosen postcodes the lat and lon matrix
map = folium.Map(location=[53,6], zoom_start = 8)
points = []

for postcodes in tour:
    location = find_location(postcodes)
    points.append(location)
    folium.Marker(location)
folium.PolyLine(points).add_to(map)
map
```

But, it returns errors in the utilities of Folium:

line 94 in validate_locations

line 94 in < listcomp >

I could not find anything on the internet so maybe someone has a clue?

Comment: What does find_location() return?  [lat, lon]?

Comment: Yeah, ['lat','lon']

Comment: that should work.  I would double check what find_location() returns.  ie `all(isinstance(p, list) for p in points)`

Comment: I added the full code to this question, points has ['lat','lon']

Comment: ok, find_location() does return a list, but a list of strings and not floats.  Try the following.  It will convert those strings to floats. 
 `folium.PolyLine(np.array(points,dtype=float), color=color_dict[j]).add_to(map)`

Comment: yes, this was indeed the problem, thank you very much!

Comment: @BobHaffner Thank You! Solved for me too